# translate the postgres ANY() operator into Node js using Massive library

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, massivejs

I am trying to update an existing postgres query in the Nodejs code base.

Below is the existing query to select based on name

```
constructor(schema){
 this.table = schema.employee_tb;
}

row = await this.table.findOne({ name });
```

Below is the Postgres query I am trying to translate and update the above code into...

```
select * from table where name = 'john' and '3467' = ANY(group_number)
```

I tried

```
row = await this.table.findOne({ name : 'john' && ANY(group_number): '3467' });
```

For which it is throwing an error.

Basically, I am trying to have the ANY operator in using the massive library.

NOTE:  group_number is character_varying[] which has data like {3467, 3455, 3421}..... the query should return the row which contains the group number in the group_number column.

Please help, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Errors usually contain very important information, if you work with a serious library. Can you add it please?

Comment: it doesn't even let me run it.  It says " ',' expected at  ANY(group_number)^: '3467'  "

Comment: Ha, yeah sure. `{ name : 'john' && ANY(group_number): '3467' }` is not valid Javascript. What library are you using, that gives you the findOne function?

Comment: @Geezus Please add the information about the node library the `findOne` function is from. That will allow people to answer

Comment: @Matt  & anarchist912 The library is Massive.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to `findOne` that has the `name` 'john' AND the `group_number` '3467', you need to update your object syntax.

```js
row = await this.table.findOne({ name : 'john', group_number : '3467' });
```

If you are using Sequelize here for the `findOne` method, I would take a look at the docs [here](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/model-querying-basics/#operators) where you can add in the ANY operator with `Op.any` in your query, but you will need to have that `character_varying[]` ready to pass into the function.

Comment: Hi Kyle this would work if the group_number is not an array! Here group_number is character_varying[] which has data like {3467, 3455, 3421,}

Comment: @Geezus where is the postgres query that you are trying to convert coming from?  The ANY operator in postgres takes in another query as it's argument.  https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-tutorial/postgresql-any/

Comment: not necessarily. The ANY operator can also be used to see if an array contains a particular value .... in the above query we are trying to find if the group_number contains 3467.

Comment: I am using a Massive Library.

Comment: Is `group_number` a column in your table or is it it's own table?

Comment: its a column in the same table.

Comment: so you're just looking for the first record where the name is John and the group_number is '3467'?  Or are you storing arrays of strings in the group_number column?

Comment: we have an array of strings in the group_numbercolumns!

Answer (score 0):

This worked!!

```
row = await this.table.where(`name = 'jhon' and '3467' = ANY(group_number)`);
```